# Why isn't the graph plotting in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the code below my graph isn't showing. Can anyone help?

Write a program using Python that does the following:

1. Prompts the user to input the name of a particular isotope and its half-life, τ, in seconds.
2. Prompts the user for an initial amount of the isotope (in grams) and an elapsed time (in seconds).
3. Calculates the amount of the isotope remaining after this elapsed time and displays the result.
4. Calculates the initial mass of the isotope (in grams) necessary to ensure that, after half a minute, 5 grams of it remain, and displays the result.
5. Plots the amount of the isotope remaining as a function of time, from elapsed time t = 0 s until t = 10 s.
6. The program should then repeat the instructions from step 1, until the user chooses to halt the program.
7. When the user wishes to enter no more isotopes, the program should display the decay plots for all of the isotopes that were entered, in a single plot, and print out a list of all the isotopes studied.

```py
#Import all packages and functions necessary for code to run

import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from numpy import empty
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# import module

#create an empty list for items to be appended later
appended_isotopes = []

#create while loop that breaks when user requests to end
while True:
   #request input from user for the name of the isotope or instruction to finish entering list of isotopes
  isotope = (input("Please enter isotope name or type 'End' when finished: "))
  
  if isotope == "End":
    # When the user has finished I diplay the studied isotopes.
    print "The isotopes entered are:", (appended_isotopes) 
    break
  else: 
   #request inputs from user for halflife in seconds, amount in grams, and time in seconds
    r = float(input("What is the halflife of the isotope in seconds?"))
    initial_amount = float(input("What is the initial amount of isotope in grams"))
    t = float(input("What is the elapsed time in seconds?"))
  
    # The amount of the isotope remaining calculated and then result printed
    P = initial_amount*np.exp(-math.log(2)*(t/r))

    print "Amount of", isotope, "remaining after", t, "seconds is:", P, "grams."
  
    # Calculate the initial mass of the isotope (in grams) necessary to ensure that, after half a minute, 5 grams of it remain
    initial_mass = float(2**(30/r))*5
    print "The initial mass of the isotope needed to ensure 5 grams remain after 30 seconds is", initial_mass, "grams."

    # plots the amount of the isotope remaining as a function of time, from elapsed time t = 0 s until t = 10 s.
  
    x=np.linspace(0,10)
    y=P
    plt.title("Graph to show amount of isotope remaining in grams (g) vs time (S)")
    plt.xlabel("Time / S")
    plt.ylabel("Amount of isotope remaining / grams (g)")
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()

    appended_isotopes.append(isotope)  #adds isotopes name to list
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line `t_range = np.arange(0,t)` to create a time line instead of just a single point

```py
t = float(input("What is the elapsed time in seconds?"))
t_range = np.arange(0,t)
P = initial_amount*np.exp(-math.log(2)*(t_range/r))
```

P is then calculated over the entire time line.

And changed

```
x=np.linspace(0,10)
y=P
```

to this to only evaluate the first 10 seconds:

```py
x=np.arange(0,10)
y=P[:10]
```

If you want the full timeline, just do this instead:

```
x=t_range
y=P
```

This gives me as many point between 0 and 10 as neccessary.

I tested with inputs "One", 100, 1000, 400 and it gave an acceptable result.